# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'ajax' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've updated wordpress to 3.5 and getting this error, j.s not working.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'ajax' of undefined

Why am I getting this error?

```
function goToIndexforsave() {
    document.getElementById('sorted_successmsg_div').innerHTML = 'processing ...';
    var img_save_url = 'http://www.holidayvillas4hire.com/index.php?page=sort_image&pid='+document.getElementById('image_sort').value;

    $.ajax({
        url: img_save_url ,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        timeout: 20000,
        error: function() {
            alert('Error loading agent favorite property.');
        },
        success: function(html) {
            document.getElementById('sorted_successmsg_div').innerHTML = html;
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to include `jquery.js` in your page by placing this line within the `<head></head>` section:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You are getting the error because the `$` variable which jQuery uses has not been instiated, and therefore the `$.ajax()` function does not exist.

Comment: It's still getting error and client said this error is occurring after she updated wordpress to 3.5, is there any solution?